# Not able to vibrate the phone on alarm

Tags: android

I am trying to build a basic Alarm app that vibrates on the time that user enters. I have just started Android , so it is just a basic app.

**I am using the concept of using the difference of current `millisecs` and the millisecs of entered time as delay in notification.vibrate method.** But, the vibration doesn't occur on the entered time.

It doesn't even occur on some other delay that i tried. I don't know what the problem is. I made a simple notification vibrating program some time back and it ran perfectly well. Any help is appreciated. But this app just force closes on Clicking the `Button`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onClick(View v)
{
 alarm();
}

protected void alarm()
{
 EditText min = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
 EditText hour = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
 EditText sec = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
 long delay =  Integer.valueOf(min.toString())*60       +Integer.valueOf(sec.toString())+Integer.valueOf(hour.toString())*3600;
 NotificationManager nm =  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, alarm2.class); //New intent to launch the other activity that would be launched when the user clicks on the notification!
 i.putExtra("id", 2);
 PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);//pendingintent p will be launched when the user clicks on notification which is in turn connected to intent i! 
 Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.notif, "Alarm !",  System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "User ALARM !", "Get up Lazy  !", p);
 notif.vibrate= new long[]{delay*1000 ,500,250,500};
 nm.notify(2, notif);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
}

}
```

Alarm2 is the second class that just does the task of terminating the notification.

Here is the `Manifest` file !

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alarm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.alarm.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".alarm2"
        android:label="alarm 2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the notification builder

```
private static NotificationCompat.Builder buildNotificationCommon(Context _context, .....) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).......;
     //Vibration
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

     //LED
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

     //Ton
        builder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));

    return builder;
   }
```

Also you can try if using `vibrator`

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

if none of this works maybe your cell phone does not have the vibration enabled or is somehow damaged

For more detailed examples you can see

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

http://javatechig.com/android/android-notification-example-using-notificationcompat

Comment: I haven't tried that. I haven't studied that yet. It would be great if you could help me with the code that i have used. Because i understand that code, Anything new at this point of time would just complicate things.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan I just added another example that you can adapt to your exisiting code

Comment: I will try that .Thanks . But i am not so sure if i would understand all of that. But i will try.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan I just added two links with more examples that can help you